# Colorize an image for overlay

Tags: android, mobile, flutter

I want to show an image from a bottle, filled with liquids in various colors. The colors exists as a RGB HEX code. So, `showBottle('#ff0000')` should show the bottle, filled with red water. My idea is to create two images: The bottle (empty), and another with just the liquid in white. These two images can then be put over another, so I can only colorize the "liquid part".

My questions:

- Is it possible to "colorize" an image in Flutter?
- What is the best way to get both images overlay each other?

EDIT:
I've tried to use the `Stack` widget and two `Image` widgets with the `colorBlendMode`, but the transparency does not work. See the image below:

```
Stack(children: <Widget>[
  Image.asset(
    'assets/images/background.png',
  ),
  Image.asset(
    'assets/images/overlay.png',
    colorBlendMode: BlendMode.color,
    color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 0, 0, 1.0),
  ),
])
```

[image]

Changing the `BlendMode` to `srcIn` will result in taking the transparency into account, but drops all information from the overlay.png image.

[image]

Comment: see [colorBlendMode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/colorBlendMode.html)

Comment: Nice! But how to colorize one image @pskink?

Comment: by using the `color` and `colorBlendMode` attributes

Comment: That does not solve my problem :( I've updated my question.

Comment: use srcIn blend mode

Comment: That will not use the overlay image, it's just the color. I've updated the question for an image.

Comment: refer to [BlendMode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/BlendMode-class.html) official docs: there are images explaining each one of 29 modes, also there are some tutorials on it like: https://medium.com/flutterpub/blend-it-like-anything-3fe67148f3f4 for example

Answer (score 0):

use image blend mode and color.
here is example,

```
Image.asset(
  'assets/image.jpg',
  height: 300,
  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
  color: _color, // Colors.red, Colors.yellow any color you want
  colorBlendMode: _blendMode, // BlendMode.color, BlendMode.darken, BlendMode.saturation, BlendMode.softLight
)
```

check [Image widget and its properties](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.asset.html)

Comment: ```colorBlendMode``` is the way to go, but does not work with transparency. I've updated my question.